# When Subclassing the UIToolBar in an iPad App to make it transparent it ends up turning black

Tags: objective-c, ipad

I'm trying to create a transparent UIToolBar in an iPad App by subclassing it.  I have seen / read several examples on how to do this, and my code looks right, but when I run my App the background is black instead of transparent.

Here is my TransparentToolBar.h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface TransparentToolBar : UIToolbar {

}


@end
```

And now my .m file:

```
#import "TransparentToolBar.h"


@implementation TransparentToolBar

// Override draw rect to avoid
// background coloring
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    // do nothing in here

}

// Set properties to make background
// translucent.
- (void) applyTranslucentBackground
{
self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
self.opaque = NO;
self.translucent = YES;
}

// Override init.
- (id) init
{
self = [super init];
[self applyTranslucentBackground];
return self;
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)aRect {
    if ((self = [super initWithFrame:aRect])) {
        [self applyTranslucentBackground];    
    }
    return self;
}


@end
```

It looks like the init functions aren't getting called, but the drawRect function is because its stripping the background that was set in IB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a view is unarchived from a XIB, the initializer that is invoked is `-initWithCoder:`

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
{
    if (self = [super initWithCoder:coder])
    {
        [self applyTransluscentBackground];
    }

    return self;
}
```